# Getting value of width:auto

Tags: javascript, css

If I have a text list, e.g.,`<br>abc<br>de<br>fghij,<br>`with `style="width:auto; height:auto;"`

**How can I get its width and height after the browser has sized it, using just JavaScript (and preferably not jQuery)?**

`blah.style.width` and `blah.style.height` return empty strings.  I'd like to get the values before making the list visible, but I can show it off screen if need be.

Comment: So you want to know the height after the document has loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .offsetWidth on an element.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.class');
el.offsetWidth
el.offsetHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get its width and height with pure javascript :

```
var width=document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;
var height=document.getElementById('foo').offsetHeight;
```

assuming that you've wrapped them in a div tag with 'foo' id

Answer (score 0):

Get the element by

```
   var p= document.getElementById("xyz");
```

Then use offsetWidth or offsetHeight to get them.

```
   p=p.offsetHeight;
```